# Hot iMac 50 degrees celsius!

Tags: imac, temperature

So i have a late 2009 21,5 iMac and whatever i do it's sooo hot!
Like right now just typing this or watching youtube it gets up to 50 degrees celsius... It does not get any hotter than that and i'm not running any specific programs that are big. I have SMC Fan control but just asking should it be that hot? I know the aluminum case works like a heatsink but really 50 celsius hot???

Comment: How are you determining the the specific temperature?  Also, can you provide a screen capture of Activity Monitor?  You can also issue the `top` command in Terminal and paste the output to your original question.

Comment: SMC Fan control says what temperature my mac is but i don't know how true it is. When i feel on the top of the iMac it is really hot.

Comment: What is telling you this temperature? Are you applying a thermometer to the outer case or are you using software to monitor the temperature sensors? This temperature is entirely normal, by the way. [This page](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/keeping-your-cool-with-apple-mac-operating-temperatures--mac-52077) discusses temperature and Mac quite adequately.

Comment: That's the CPU temp.  Since I don't know exactly which CPU you have, I can't give you an exact answer, but Core2Duo CPU's generally have max temps in the 70C, so your CPU is not too hot.  See this site:  http://ark.intel.com/products/family/79667/Legacy-Intel-Core2-Processor#@Desktop

Comment: Well i read what was on the page and it seems that my iMac is running as it is suppose to do. SMC Fan Control is a software were i can see temperatures thru the temperature sensors. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please be kind a flag the comment as helpful (You may also want to "answer your own question"

Comment: I don't see the option to mark comment's as helpful only answers. I would if i could!

Comment: Hover just to the left of it...you will see an arrow and a flag.  Click the arrow!

Comment: 50 degrees is not hot. My MacBook Air gets 100deg C whenever doing HD gaming, 3D stuff, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 21.5-inch, Late 2009, iMac has either a [E7600](http://ark.intel.com/products/41495/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7600-3M-Cache-3_06-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB) or [E8600](http://ark.intel.com/products/35605/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E8600-6M-Cache-3_33-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) Intel Core 2 Duo with a TCASE (Case Temperature is the maximum temperature allowed at the processor Integrated Heat Spreader (IHS).) temperature of 74.1°C and 72.4°C respectively.  So if the CPU is reading only 50°C, then it's not running hot at all.